# If i have a testnet aplication, is necesary deploy it to the mainnet?

Tags: testnet

The transaction cost in the testnet is zero, so I am not sure if it is portable to the main net -- do transactions on the main net have cost?

Answer (score 3):

No need. The testnet is parallel to the real network, neither of which will have transactions.

Comment: Wow! perfect, i came from Ethereum, i´m new in Iota , i go to study it here, Tks

Answer (score 2):

There are no transaction fees neither in mainnet nor in testnet. I recommend using the mainnet.

Comment: Wow! perfect, i came from Ethereum, i´m new in Iota, i go to study it here, Tks

Comment: Note that there is a 1 Miota dust limit on mainnet addresses, so if you need to test scenarios with many different addresses, you need some "real money". On the testnet you can get a few Miota from the faucet easily.